# Can a Tiny Servant use a Wand of Magic Missiles?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, animated-objects

Is it possible for a creature created by the [*tiny servant*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-servant) spell (XGtE, p. 168) to wield and use a magic item, such as a [*wand of magic missiles*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-magic-missiles)?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Answer (score 15):

## Yes, it can use the wand

The creature animated by [*tiny servant*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/tiny-servant) is a creature and the spell places no restrictions on what kind of actions it can take, or be commanded to take.

> As a bonus action, you can mentally command the creature if it is within 120 feet of you. [...] You decide what action the creature will take and where it will move during its next turn [...]

Therefore, it is able to use any general magic items, including a [wand of magic missiles](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/wand-of-magic-missiles).

For other magic items, a tiny servant can even attune to (up to three) magic items, but not ones that have requirements (such as being a spellcaster) that it does not fulfil (such as the *wand of fireballs*). It is also limited by its carrying capacity — which for a Tiny creature with a Strength of 4 is 30 lb — but this is not a problem for most items.

Comment: @DaleM Wand of magic missiles does not require attunement, so there is nothing to say that it can't

Comment: Even if it required attunement [they could attune to it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107328) since that's something [even an animal can do](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115569)

Comment: There is an extra requirement that might come into play - command word. The tiny servant has no mouth or vocal apparatus. So, it can use a wand of magic missiles but not a broom of flying.