# How can live fire exercises be made safer?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, campaign-development, campaign-settings

My group is in [Waterdeep](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Waterdeep), and our wizard would love to help train the world-famous [griffon cavalry](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Griffon_Cavalry), especially in evading fireballs. That is, he wants to hurl fireballs at them that they need to evade.

I think this kind of [live fire exercise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_fire_exercise) is eminently worthwhile. (A nice spectacle for the populace, too.)

However, the griffons involved (and their riders) presumably would prefer some assurance they will not be singed *too much*.

How can we make this kind of live fire exercise safer for the targets?

- One immediate possibility would be [*Protection from Energy*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Protection%20from%20Energy#content), which confers resistance from one kind of energy, like fire. Prior to the exercise, someone could cast this spell at the griffon and rider. Unfortunately, even resistance only halves the damage involved, which can still be somewhat painful.
- [*Enhance Ability (Cat's Grace)*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Enhance%20Ability#content) would help with the Dexterity saving throws. (Edit: doh. Of course it only helps with ability checks, not saving throws. Thanks [@PeterCordes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/15436/peter-cordes).)
- Something like the Rogue's or the Monk's Evasion ability would also be useful, but the griffons don't have that. The [*Ring of Evasion*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-evasion) requires attunement, and with the griffons' Intelligence of 2, I don't quite see how they would attune to the ring (on a claw?).

---

Additional info in response to comments:

- Yes, live fire exercises are dangerous, and therefore not used in RL by "good" organizations. However, they are *useful*. In a world where magic exists, it may be there is a way these useful exercises can be run in a magically safe way by "good" organizations.
- There is no rules-mechanical goal, only a narrative one. Or, if you prefer, I'll say that this is how the griffon cavalry gets XP so they can level up and then be better able to withstand Fireballs (through higher HPs, for instance).

Comment: In real life, live-fire exercises are typically performed against plywood targets, drones, and similar. The trainees are issued real ammo, but the targets are not other living people. (A "Hogan's Alley" course is live-fire training, for example.) There are a few historical examples where trainees are firing real bullets at other trainees, but that's typically considered extreme and unnecessary. In the context of D&D, I suspect this would most likely be the act of an evil organization.

Comment: To your third bullet point, this question may help: [Can an animal attune to a magic item?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/115569/can-an-animal-attune-to-a-magic-item)

Comment: @DarthPseudonym: well, it's precisely because I'd like to treat my group and the local populace to some (more or less) harmless *Fireballs* in a good- or at least neutral-aligned organization that I'm looking for a way to do this without harming the griffons...

Comment: What's the purpose of this training?  I could see some sort of narrative sense for a novel's description of such activity, but mechanically, there is no dodging a fireball, except for the Dex save mechanic (with modifiers, like Evasion).  There could be tactics that help, "spread out so they can only hit one of us!", but I'm not sure that is what you are describing.   What is the mechanical goal of this training?

Comment: @MichaelRichardson: I'll happily admit that there is indeed no mechanical goal, only a narrative one. Or, if you prefer, I'll say that this is how the griffon cavalry gets XP so they can level up and then be better able to withstand *Fireballs* (through higher HPs, for instance).

Comment: A reminder to all: [Don't answer in the comments.](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/33569) Comments are for suggesting improvements to the question or requesting clarification about the question itself, not for partial/speculative answers. And Stephan, you should edit any necessary/relevant clarifications (e.g. the goal of this training) into the question itself, as comments can be cleaned up at any time.

Comment: Enhance Ability only helps with Ability Checks, not Saving Throws.  Otherwise yes, good idea, learning how it feels to dodge a fireball can get a rookie on the right track.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume you're the DM. If not so, please disregard this answer.

---

Give them access to a simple, homebrew magic item that turns their spells into harmless bombs of paint while the spellcaster is wearing it:

> ***Te'Sar's Magical Marksmanship Training Device***
>
> This simple silver ring has a small, colorful gem on it, that changes
> color when the wearer snaps their fingers - cycling between blue, red,
> yellow, and green.
>
> While wearing this ring, all of your spells explode in colorful,
> harmless bombs of paint. Creatures that would be damaged by any spell
> you cast are instead covered in ink of the same color as the color of the gem on
> the ring. If the spell allows for a saving throw, only creatures that
> fail the check are covered in paint.

This is a simple solution that avoid a lot of headaches, and shouldn't break the balance of your game in any serious manner. More so, if you need a way for them to *acquire* said thing, you can always make them research the area a bit and hear from such devices from a bard or something of the type, them go visit the nearby wizard and do a simple quest or two in exchange for it.

---

Comment: I am indeed the DM, and this is a fun idea. I wonder how much I would need to nudge my players until they see the possibility of "borrowing" one of these rings and slipping it to one of the BBEGs. I think there might be a cursed version of these rings around that masquerade as *Rings of Protection* or similar.

Comment: @StephanKolassa To solve issues with the group finding the proper magic items when dealing with things like wealth by level and so (on Pathfinder), I introduced _The Magical Mysteries Magazine_. It is a "product catalog/variety magazine) that, among other things, allows you to order magic items to be delivered to any registered inn by a magic courier. It supposedly works as some sort of Adventurer E-bay - adventurers buy and sell their unneeded/outdated loot to each other all over the land using it, and the magazine's owners collect a fee. It is silly, but it works.

Comment: @StephanKolassa It also creates the interesting dynamic of players from different groups selling stuff to each other's characters. It is even better when, five or so adventures down the line, someone leaves a comment on something that was previously sold by someone else: "Don't buy. Paid for a Rod of Enlarge Spells. Didn't contain any enlargement spell." or "Bag of Holding had a few burnt marks but worked perfectly. Good finish. Worth the price.", etc.

Comment: This item is outstanding. I'm going to use it in my campaign. In a horrible way of course.. +1 for sure!!

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because it makes the most *narrative* sense. The [Watchful Order of Magists and Protectors](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Watchful_Order_of_Magists_and_Protectors) in Waterdeep, which organizes these trainings, will have a number of these rings available for precisely this scenario. If the party's Rogue succeeds in abstracting one, and the party slips it to the BBEG, Much Fun Will Ensue. Thanks!

Answer (score 48):

### Use Faerie Fire as a surrogate for Fireball

Advantages:

- Faerie Fire is non-lethal.
- Like Fireball, Faerie Fire uses a Dexterity saving throw.
- Targets who fail the save light up, making it easy to determine who failed.
- Faerie Fire is a 1st level spell, so your wizard should have significantly more of them available for training on any given day.

Disadvantages:

- Faerie Fire targets a 20 foot cube (an area effect, but quite a bit smaller than a 20 foot radius fireball).
- Faerie Fire only has a range of 60 feet vs fireball's 150 ft.
- Faerie Fire is a Druid spell, and not on the Wizard's spell list. (Curse you 5e!)

A few disadvantages, but as a training exercise for Dexterity saves, maybe they're acceptable, although having to hire a druid probably makes this a non-starter...

Alternately you could use Darkness or Fog Cloud, but they are harder to judge since they don't require a Dexterity saving throw.

Comment: This is helpful, as in "now the druid in the party also has something to do"... Thanks!

Comment: If you use a simulated fireball, it isn't really life-fire anymore, it's a military field exercise or wargame.  (Not that this is a bad thing!)

Comment: To pair this with @Bearmarshal s answer, at a glance I don't think it would be too unblanced to create a "Faerie Fire 2.0", that has the same range and footprint as fireball, and call it a 2nd level spell instead of a 1st. That still gives plenty of slots, and if you're feeling generous as a DM (i would be), let the Wizard and Druid work together on its creation and it can go in both their spell lists (the power of Teamwork!)

Comment: @JamesOtter Faerie Fire 2.0? Nah - call it Faerie Ball for maximum puns.

Comment: @T.Sar Sphere of Lights?

Answer (score 30):

### Have the player research a non-lethal training fireball

Real world militaries have spent considerable amounts of R&D resources developing training equipment to create exercises as faithful to real combat experience as possible without any danger of physical injuries, so it's not unreasonable to argue that the same should have to be done in-game.

There are (as far as I'm aware) still no official rules for researching your own spells in 5E, but there should be a number of house rules floating around the Internet, and if you don't mind winging some numbers, "X weeks, Y gold and an Arcana check" should suffice. Especially for a spell that doesn't really need much balancing.

If the player wants to improvise something here and now, however, I agree with the people suggesting *Faerie Fire* or *Death Ward*. Neither are optimal for training exercises, but that's a point in itself.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: I think this approaches the problem in the way the OP most intends, and I don't think that a DM would have much reason to object to a Fireball variant in the wizard's arsenal that merely does superficial damage. In fact, if I was DMing this game, I might suggest that while learning Fireball the wizard would have been using a low-damage version of the spell to prevent burning down their surroundings while mastering the spell and could cast their existing Fireball with this variation.

Answer (score 13):

### When Death is cheap, let them die (*briefly*)

A bit of a frame challenge here, but a real-life "live fire scenario" takes significant precautions because any damage they cause is, generally, irreversible or cannot be fully mitigated. With time, broken bones can heal and torn muscles can stitch themselves back together, but an accidental amputation and/or death is relatively permanent.

In fantasy settings like the Forgotten Realms, this isn't necessarily the case. Almost any type of injury and even death can be perfectly reversed with some sort of magic (if at a cost). In the case of *fireball*, there are no RAW lingering effects to taking damage from one (except for unattended flammable objects, which don't seem to be in danger here). So enough healing spells or healing potions will fully reverse the damage. In the event something does go exceedingly wrong, clerics capable of casting *revivify* might be available as well.

A 3rd-level *fireball* spell deals a maximum of 48 damage and an average of 28. [Griffons (MM.174)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/griffon) have 59 (7d10+21) hit points, so they should be quite capable of surviving at least one failed saving throw, although the second one would cut it close. A [Veteran (MM.350)](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/veteran) likewise has 58 (9d8+18) hit points and should be capable of the same. More generally, any character with 25 or more hit points is not at risk of instant death from even a maximum damage casting (although fall damage could be an issue) as long as they can quickly make it to a source of healing.

In summary, consider whether these griffon riders can be persuaded to take the damage anyways if appropriate precautions are taken to heal them afterwards. Learning to dodge a *fireball* is well and good, but knowing what one feels like and how to maintain composure and control afterwards is valuable experience as well. Because the "enemy" caster is actually a friendly, anyone who does take a hit should be able to escape the exercise safely to seek aid without having to worry about taking additional strikes. You can even turn this into a joint exercise with groups of local clerics to give them opportunities to practice casting these healing spells.

Comment: A couple of clerics loaded to the gills with Healing Word ought to suffice for the combat medic / triage function, with a spare Revivify or two just in case.

Comment: A Grave cleric with bonus-action 30ft range Spare the Dying can be a good backup in case of miscommunication about how many spell slots the healers have left.  Although you really want more range to cover a larger area, so yeah Healing Word is good.  Mass Cure Wounds can reach out to 60 + 30 ft range, but a cleric can't Dash on the same turn they cast it (unless they multi-class rogue or monk), and it's a 5th level spell.

Comment: For longer-range healing, Circle of Dreams druids get Balm of the Summer Court at 2nd level: 120 ft range, number of uses per long rest = druid level (if you only use 1d6 at a time).  It's not a spell so presumably you could do it while wildshaped into something fast, like a giant eagle, without needing to be 18th level to cast spells in beast form.

Comment: I envisioned this more like playing paintball with fireballs - one hit and you're out, leave the field. In that context, Prayer of Healing is incredibly efficient, albeit completely unusable in an active combat situation (2nd level, 10 minute casting time, 6 creatures within 30 feet regain 2d8+SPELL hp)

Answer (score 10):

### Sculpt Spell

The level 2 evocation wizard feature *Sculpt Spell* (PBH, pg. 117) allows you to take it easy on the trainees. The wizard can select up to three creatures they can see. Those three creatures automatically succeed on their saving throw, and take no damage on a successful save.

Every evocation wizard will have this. And if you aren't an evocation specialist, why would the griffon cavalry even hire you for an evocation-specific training?

Comment: Hm. "And if you aren't an evocation specialist, why would the griffon cavalry even hire you for an evocation-specific training?" - because every *Fireball* is helpful in this training. And no, the character is an enchanter, so I would prefer a solution that can be applied by (potentially other) wizards and/or items.

Comment: If you use Sculpt Spell, how do you distinguish between troops who are succeeding their saves and those who are failing?

Comment: You don't. You select which units automatically pass.

Comment: @indigochild I think Darth’s point is that this solution makes it appear as though everyone passes, even if they wouldn’t have passed, which makes it difficult to provide meaningful feedback for training.

Comment: This seems like a flavour quest, surely there's no game mechanic (other than feats and leveling up) that allows training to improve saving throws. as such working feedback is not needed.

Answer (score 9):

## [Major Image](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/major-image)

This spell is the closest you can get to replicating a Fireball with 5E's (admittedly limited selection of) illusion spells.

It is a 3rd level spell, with a range of 120 feet, covering a 20 foot cube.  It creates not only visual and audio cues, but even heat.  And it doesn't do any damage.

You can also move and alter the appearance of the illusion, so it could effectively be be a different fireball every turn for the 10 minute duration.

## Role Play it

What is your intended result here, out of game?

Do you actually expect the griffin riders to gain a mechanical benefit in game?  Do you want to simulate a fight with these characters, just without lethal results?  Or is this a more about the role playing and the interaction?

Because if you are not concerned with the actual fight, just role play it.  Other than a few potential social skill checks, don't worry too much about the spells and the damage and all that crunch.  Ask the wizard for an Arcana check to make sure he can 'barely miss' or 'control the damage' of an actual Fireball.  Let him use Major Image but scale it up to perfectly replicate Fireball.

Of course, if you are planning on an ambush before the wizard can take a long rest to recover his spells, that might be a different story.

Also, I want to point out, in game, that relying on spells or items like Cat's Grace that they might not have access to in real combat, defeats the point of the training.  Reducing the damage with Protection from Energy is fine if they are learning to dodge, but giving them Evasion or improved Dex saves is not.

Comment: Items and spells (and bardic inspiration) that help you pass the save could be useful for rookies that aren't as good at dodging yet, to see what it feels like to dodge correctly.  It's not taking over your body, you still feel how you moved.  You'd still want to graduate to real training without "training wheels", though.  (Lowering the Wizard's Int to reduce the spell-save DC would be more of a problem; easier to dodge fireballs are probably even less good training.  They're still fireballs and still do half damage on save, though, so it does create familiarity with danger and damage.)

Answer (score 4):

**Melf's Minute Meteors plus some source of Temp HP should make things very easily survivable**, if still somewhat painful, and give you 6 small fireball-like effects per 3rd-level spell slot.  An Inspiring Leader (feat) can grant temp HP to many small groups over the course of a day.

---

If you want to go fully non-damaging (like druid faerie fire), **a wizard could help out with other non-damaging spells** like Pyrotechnics (2nd lvl, con save to avoid blinded for a turn).  Makes flight-into-terrain possible, depending on how upset the Griffon's other senses are, especially balance / sense of up and down.  Could certainly help birds + riders get used to flying in battle conditions with spells going off near them.  Color Spray (1st) is somewhat similar but too short range (only 15 ft).

Other useful non-damaging spells to train saving throws with:

- **Earthbind (2nd)** to train in resisting that spell; definitely something you want flyers to prepare for when training to go up against spell casters.
- Cause Fear (1st) - 60 ft range, single target.  wis save repeated until success (concentration, 1 min)
- Tasha's Hideous Laughter (1st) - 30 ft range, Wis save or fall prone / incapacitated.
- Gust of Wind (2nd) to create adverse flying conditions: 60 ft long, 10 ft wide line of wind from the caster.  Str save or be pushed backward if you *start* your turn in it.  (Or Warding Wind (2nd) if you want to buzz past a levitating or flying wizard.)
- Hold Person (2nd) on the riders only - Wis save.
- Ray of Enfeeblement (2nd) 60 ft range, Con save every turn until successful (1 min concentration).  Mechanically, no ill effects except for reduced attack damage.  But you could rule that it makes it tiring to fly, or harder to hold on under other adverse conditions if you combine effects.
- Fear (3rd) 30 ft cone, Wis save until success (conc. 1 min), unlimited creatures.
- Hypnotic Pattern (3rd) to train is Wis saves.  (incapacitate / speed 0, so you need falling protection unless someone can "shake the creature awake" before hitting the ground.)
- Sleet Storm (3rd) 20 ft tall, 40 ft radius cylinder centered within range=120ft.  Dex save or fall prone because of the ground being "covered with slick ice".  DM ruling on whether this has a mechanical effect on fliers, e.g. riders maybe slipping off their mounts?  It's at least adverse conditions to spring on your trainees at least once.
- Stinking Cloud (3rd) Con save against poison to lose your action "retching and reeling"
- Slow (3rd) - 6 creatures with one cast, AoE Wis saves repeated until success (1 min conc.)
- Storm Sphere (4th) - 20 ft radius sphere, 60 ft range, Str save to avoid 2d6 bludgeoning.  Sounds awesome, and flying through the wind can be good training to stay on the Griffon.  (Concentration for 1 minute, can use a bonus action to shoot lighting 60 ft, attack roll for 4d6 on hit.  This part can train their dex?)
- Skywrite (rit. 2nd) to create a harmless "obstacle" course
- Message (cantrip) to help with communication between instructors and riders.
- Feather Fall (1st) to spare the rider's rings (which are single-use magic items).
- I stopped looking after 4th level wizard spells.

A Levitating or Flying wizard could cast these from some height, making the shorter-range effects useful for training without having to fly quite close to the ground.

An 18th level wizard can prepare any 1st and 2nd level wizard spells as their "spell mastery" slot to cast it at will.  Takes 8 hours to re-spec this, but one very high level wizard can give many Griffon riders a full day's training against non-damaging effects.  (Their save DC will be really difficult unless something temporarily reduces their Int without stopping them from casting spells...)

**There are also less-damaging-than-fireball spells**, notably the 2nd-level AoE low-budget fireball spells.

- Aganazzar's Scorcher (2nd) only 30 ft line :( 3d8 fire, dex for half
- Snilloc's Snowball Swarm (2nd) 90 ft range, only 5ft radius, 3d6 cold, dex save for half.
- Shatter (2nd) is a Con save for half of 3d8 Thunder. (60 ft range, 10 ft radius)
- Ice Knife (1st) bursts for AoE damage (hit or miss on the initial attack roll), dex save for half.
- **Melf's Minute Meteors (3rd) - 6 tiny fireballs with one cast**: 120 ft range, 5ft burst radius, **only 2d6 fire**, dex save for half.  You send them one or two per round, concentration for 10mins.

**There are some cheapish ways to grant temporary HP**, like a Shepherd Druid's bear spirit totem (AoE 5+druid level upon placing it, unlimited number of creatures within 30ft radius of it.  Only once per rest, though.)  Or spells like Heroism could refresh to 5 temp HP every round for a minute.  (Concentration from a Bard of Paladin).

**Inspiring Leader** can give level+cha mod temp HP to up to 6 creatures who spend 10 minutes listening to their drill sergeant / instructor.  The limit on repeated use is on the creature receiving the temp HP: one high-level instructor can repeat their speech to a new flight of cadets every 10 minutes, but each group can't refresh the buff until after a short rest.  Aid will also raise 3 creature's actual max HP.  (A Wizard can't do this part, but you'll want someone around anyway with Healing Word prepped.)

---

If it's possible to temporarily lower the Wizard's Int, that would lower the save DC, making it easier for rookies to get started dodging something.  However, it might be better training to learn what it feel like to dodge a difficult spell, e.g. via Bless and/or Bardic Inspiration.  (**Note that Enhance Ability only helps with *ability checks*, not saves**.)

---

As suggested by others in comments, having a healer or two on the ground with Healing Word is a good idea (1st level, 60 ft range, bonus action so you can move + dash + healing word).

Or a Circle of Dreams druids with Balm of the Summer Court (2nd level): 120 ft range, number of uses per long rest = druid level (if you only use 1d6 at a time). It's not a spell so presumably you could do it while wildshaped into something fast, like a giant eagle, without needing to be 18th level to cast spells in beast form.

Possibly a Grave Cleric for 30 ft range Spare the Dying in case of accidents when spell slots are exhausted.  It *can* be cast as a Bonus Action for a grave cleric, so you could do it after Dashing. Or Spare 2 creatures per turn with Action and Bonus, if no AoE heal like a Life cleric's Channel Divinity AoE, or Mass Healing Word, is available.

Answer (score 2):

## Damage is not harm

### No additional work!

In 5E, hit points do not represent (solely) bodily integrity, and the loss of them does not represent lasting harm. To quote the PHB:

> Hit Points represent a combination of physical and mental durability, the will to live, and luck. Creatures with more Hit Points are more difficult to kill. Those with fewer Hit Points are more fragile.

Though it is often roleplayed as such, a hit that deals damage does not *necessarily* do harm. Especially when simulating something like aerial combat, I would recommend using hitpoints to represent things like positioning in the saddle, control of mount, and mental fortitude / concentration.

A griffin rider at half HP after a few player attacks might not be bleeding or bruised — but barely hanging onto their reins, out of formation with his fellows, and missing a stirrup.

Using the Waterdeep stats for the Griffin Rider Cavalry, they have 9d8+18 HP. A direct hit from a fireball will do, at most, 8d6 damage, and only ignites items that "aren't being worn and carried". Your wizard can throw fireballs with impunity without worrying about killing anyone, and you, as the DM, are free to represent that damage as non-lethal, and RAW, as not having even harmed the griffon cavalry's gear.

A "hit" from a fireball in this context is enough of a near-miss that the griffon and rider are either forced to land, or the rider is forced to bail from their griffon and rely on their featherfall ring to protect them.

Answer (score 1):

### Air Space Management

Fireball has a range or 150 feet, and an AoE of 20 foot radius. Require your wizard to stand in a small area, and have lookouts surrounding him at a 180 foot radius. Have lookouts flying at 180 directly above the wizard to make a "dome" around him.

Any rider who enters the dome has lost control of their mount, and is "killed." This is like having a "hard deck" in a flight exercise.

Put fake-wizard-decoys at about 200 feet from the real wizard - the riders are tasked with attacking the decoys while dodging attacks from the real wizard.

A second set of lookouts act as referees - they stand near the decoys and determine hits. The wizard fires on the riders, and these lookouts determine if the shot would have connected if they were at the proper range.

Lookouts can cast faerie fire to mark successful attacks. Riders allow FF hits to land without dodging / rolling.

At no point is either the wizard or the rider in danger, but everyone gets a good show.

Answer (score -1):

Death Ward on all participants, to keep accidental fatalities to a minimum.
Ring of feather fall on riders, i do not believe it requires attunement.
As for attuning the griffins,  I'm fairly certain, RAW, a character can use their own attunement slots to instead attune an item to a follower, mount, pet, etc.
Non-combat casters round the perimeter with dimension door on standby to pull out "fallen" combatants,  and prompt healing for if things go amiss.
Just a couple thoughts to add to the other contributions.

Comment: This could be improved by explaining why Death Ward is the best option... and possibly addressing how to manage them dropping to 1 HP and retreating the test zone.

Comment: This answer would be greatly improved with more certainty on the validity of the solution proposed. Specifically, "I'm fairly certain, RAW, a character can use their own attunement slots to instead attune an item to a follower..."

Comment: "I'm fairly certain, RAW, a character can use their own attunement slots to instead attune an item to a follower, mount, pet, etc." - This is incorrect. [There are a number of Q&As about whether an animal, familiar, etc. can attune to magic items](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/115569?lq=1) - RAW, nothing prevents any creature from attuning to a magic item as long as it can follow the [rules for attunement](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/magic-items#Attunement) (i.e. "spend[ing] a short rest focused on only that item while being in physical contact with it").

Comment: In addition, answers should generally answer the question independently, and you should elaborate on your suggestions to explain why they're the best solution(s) to the problem. Right now, your answer just mentions a bunch of ideas with barely a line of explanation for each.